# Vector addition to calculate velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors

Im working on a vector addition problem where I'm given the magnitude and direction of two vectors.  In this problem, a plane flying in the jet stream.  My first thought was to get the X/Y components of each vector by taking its sin and cos, and then adding them together but thats not working.  Then i tried to get theta by taking the inverse tan of the sum X/Y components i calculated but Im also not doing something right in this calculation.  Am I at least on the right track?

Comment: What does your vector addition diagram look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is called polar addition of vectos. We call the plane's polar velocity vector r1 and the jet stream's r2.
here is how you handle it:
$$r=\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2+2r_1r_2\cos (\phi_2-\phi_1)}$$

We have an aluminum or cardboard slide ruller in the cockpit basically a slide-ruller with a rotating graduated circle called E6-B flight computer costing $10.00 which allows you to do instant calculation of these kinds and many more.

Answer (score 0):

You should have been able to get the components in just the way you said-- find the x and y components of each vector, using sine and cosine of the direction angle for that vector, and then add the x1 to x2 and the y1 to y2.  You end up with the coordinates of the total, so if you need a magnitude, use the Pythagorean theorem, and if you need an angle to the x axis, find the arctan of y/x.